# Entity Framework Database First Stored Procedure with different return types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure called CreatePrice and have added it to the edmx file(database first) I can see it under function import in the model browser and all is good. The generated function looks like this:

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<CreatePrice_Result> CreatePrice(string type, string code, string userName, Nullable<bool> export)
{
    var typeParameter = type != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("Type", type) :
        new ObjectParameter("Type", typeof(string));

    var codeParameter = code != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("Code", code) :
        new ObjectParameter("Code", typeof(string));

    var userNameParameter = userName != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("UserName", userName) :
        new ObjectParameter("UserName", typeof(string));

    var exportParameter = export.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("Export", export) :
        new ObjectParameter("Export", typeof(bool));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<CreatePrice_Result>("CreatePrice", typeParameter, codeParameter, userNameParameter, exportParameter);
}
```

The return type is like this:

```
public partial class CreatePrice_Result
{
    public string ActiveDate { get; set; }
    public string ActiveTime { get; set; }
    public string InactiveDate { get; set; }
    public string InactiveTime { get; set; }
}
```

This is where my problem comes in. The DB Admin who created the stored procedure returns a resultset if the "export" argument is set to true and returns a value of 0 if the "export" argument  is set to false.The generated code doesn't seem to understand this.

If I execute the stored procedure and set the value to false. I get this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'CreatePrice_Result'. A member of the type, 'ActiveDate', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I guess the simplest thing to do is to ask the DB Admin to amend the  stored procedure to return a result set regardless of the value of export but this defeats the point of that argument because if it is set to false, I don't need it.

Is there a way I can get the generated code to handle both scenarios i.e handle both the return types. Also I'm trying to avoid manual changes in the generated code because of it being overwritten.

I tried changing the return type to be object and tried to return a different result based on the "export" argument

```
if (export == null || export == false)
{
   return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<int>("CreatePrice", typeParameter, codeParameter, userNameParameter, exportParameter);
}
else
{
   return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<CreatePrice_Result>("CreatePrice", typeParameter, codeParameter, userNameParameter, exportParameter);    
}
```

but I get this error:

> The type parameter 'System.Int32' in ExecuteFunction is incompatible with the type 'CreatePrice_Result' returned by the function.

Thanks

Comment: If export is false you don't to call the SP at all?

Comment: @artm the stored procedure is executed in both scenarios ( it populates other tables), the only difference is if export is true, it returns a resultset of that info and if it is set to false it returns 0

Comment: I had a look but can't find anything about the same SP returning multiple return types. Not ideal but all I can think of is if Export is false, put a try catch. Other solution is to ask DB admin to return `NULL AS ActiveDate, NULL AS ActiveTime...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it can be done without resorting to ADO.NET objects.  However, you can use the `ObjectContext.Translate<TElement>` method to map the results to entity objects and optionally track the results in an entity set.  Demo code below:

SQL sproc:

```
create proc dbo.FuzzyResultSet
(
    @mode int
)
as

if( @mode = 1 )
begin
    -- execute non-query
    return @mode
end
else if( @mode = 2 )
begin
    -- execute scalar
    select @mode
end
else
begin
    -- execute reader
    select * from dbo.Watches
end
```

C# code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        using( var db = new DBFirst.EFMREntities() )
        {
            db.Database.Initialize( force: false );

            try
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Open();

                var objContext = ( db as IObjectContextAdapter ).ObjectContext;

                // mode 0 returns a result set
                var reader = GetCmd( db, 0 ).ExecuteReader();
                var entityResults = objContext
                    .Translate<DBFirst.Watch>( reader, 
                        // next two parms only if you want results in an entity set
                        "Watches", MergeOption.OverwriteChanges );

                // mode 2 returns a scalar
                var scalarResult = GetCmd( db, 2 ).ExecuteScalar();

                // mode 1 does not return a result set
                var cmd = GetCmd( db, 1 );
                var nonQueryResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var nonQueryReturnParm = cmd.Parameters[ "@RETURN_VALUE" ];
                var nqrpValue = Convert.IsDBNull( nonQueryReturnParm.Value ) ? null : ( int? )nonQueryReturnParm.Value;

                Console.WriteLine( "Entities returned: {0}", entityResults.Count() );
                Console.WriteLine( "Scalar result: {0}", scalarResult );
                Console.WriteLine( "Non-query results: {0} / {1}", nonQueryResult, nqrpValue );
            }
            finally
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Close();
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static DbCommand GetCmd( DbContext context, int value )
    {
        var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();

        var inParm = cmd.CreateParameter();
        inParm.ParameterName = "@mode";
        inParm.Value = value;

        var outParm = cmd.CreateParameter();
        outParm.ParameterName = "@RETURN_VALUE";
        outParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.FuzzyResultSet";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange( new []{ inParm, outParm } );

        return cmd;
    }
}
```